# Tkinter text widget search and show

Tags: python, search, tkinter, widget

i was able to create a text widget with a search, and highlight every finding. The only thing i miss is a button like "Next" which jumps to the next finding.
So far i was not even able to show (jump) to the first finding.
I can move the cursor there, but i cant move the screen.

The text widget has a huge ammount of text, and i use a scrollbars if that can help.

Is there any way to move the screen or scrollbar to the curzor? Or to a tag? Or to a finding?

Thanks, Gábor

Comment: Could be a good idea to post at least the relevant parts of your existing code (?)

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [yview](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.yview-method) methods to scroll the widget by a particular amount. However, for this specific use case the text widget has the [see](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method) method, which arranges for a given index to be visible.

From the official tcl/tk documentation (upon which Tkinter is built):

> [see] Adjusts the view in the window so that the character given by
>   index is completely visible. If index is already visible then the
>   command does nothing. If index is a short distance out of view, the
>   command adjusts the view just enough to make index visible at the edge
>   of the window. If index is far out of view, then the command centers
>   index in the window.